# Function to duplicate and mark duplicated text

Tags: region, mark, yank, kill-ring

In order to be able to chain the following command, I need the yanked text to be marked. That is because the end goal is to call `(pop kill-ring)` so that I can still use whatever was at the top of the kill-ring before duplicating.

I think all of that could be avoided if there was a way to duplicate region without using the kill-ring.

```el
(defun me/duplicate-downward (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (kill-region begin end)
  (yank)
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (push-mark)
    (yank)
    (setq mark-active t)))
```

#### Results

Region is correctly duplicated, but region isn't active.

#### Expected behavior

`[]` is region, `|` is point.

Before:

```
[Lorem
 ipsum]
|
```

After:

```
 Lorem
 ipsum
[Lorem
 ipsum]
|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this method because @JohnKitchin's leaves the region *open*. ie. Moving point de/increases the region.

```el
(defun me/duplicate-downward (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let (deactivate-mark (point (point)))
    (insert (buffer-substring begin end))
    (push-mark point)))

(defun me/duplicate-upward (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (save-excursion
      (insert (buffer-substring begin end)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```el
(defun j/dd (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (insert (buffer-substring begin end))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char end)
      (set-mark-command nil))))
```